# C# - Error With Getting Data From mySQL Database

Tags: c#, mysql

I am currently getting an error when trying to get data from mySQL:

```
Additional information: Could not find specified column in results: admin
```

My code is:

```
public int getLevel()
    {
        string sqlCommand = "Select level from users where username = 'admin'";
        int value = 0;

        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("host=111.222.111.222;user=MYUSERNAME;password=MYPASSWORD;database=tcg;");
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sqlCommand, con);

        con.Open();

        MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            value += int.Parse(reader.GetString("admin"));
        }
        return value;
    }
```

Comment: you are only bringing back column `level`

Comment: Before you start coding too much, utilize `using` blocks for safe resource use. Otherwise all your code will look like the above :p

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to get the data of level

Comment: Then why do you have `GetString("admin"));`

Comment: If you have never worked with resultsets before then just say so and someone can maybe type up an answer. But it is like Hour 1 of a tutorial and stackoverflow is not that kind of a site

Comment: Lol thank you @Drew for you edit and finding that line with GetString("Admin")); :) +1 for you It was supposed to be GetString("level"));

Comment: is this `mysql` or `sql-server` ? It is tagged mysql but @ShannonHolsinger has `TOP` below (sql-server)

Comment: Whoops - old habits...... editing now.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
 public int getLevel()
 {
     int value = 0;
     using(MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("host=45.37.80.181;user=MYUSERNAME;password=MYPASSWORD;database=tcg;"))
     {
         con.Open();
         using(MySqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
         {
             cmd.CommandText = "Select level from users where username = @ad";
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ad","admin");
             MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

             while (reader.Read())
             {
                 value += int.Parse(reader[0]);
             }
        }
        con.Close();
     }
     return value;
}
```

If you only have one admin, use:

```
public int getLevel()
 {
     int value = 0;
     using(MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("host=45.37.80.181;user=MYUSERNAME;password=MYPASSWORD;database=tcg;"))
     {
         con.Open();
         using(MySqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
         {
             cmd.CommandText = "Select level from users where username = @ad";//add Order by if you need to
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ad","admin");
             value += Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar());//this assumes you will get an integer value

        }
        con.Close();
     }
     return value;
}
```

Comment: Not sure why you got a DV. Here is one up. Thx for helping the op

Comment: 'cause I put TOP in the SELECT statement which is SQL not MySQL. Someone got their panties in a bunch before I could edit it. No worries - glad it helped. Cheers!